# Joining Three Tables MySQL -

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables named

**CV Table**

```
-------------
id    name
-------------
1     Arthur
2     James
3     John
4     king
```

**Tech Table**

```
-------------
id    name
-------------
1     Java
2     C#
3     PHP
4     Python
```

**Bridge**

```
    -----------------
   CV_id    tech_id
    -----------------
       1     1
       1     2
       1     3
       1     4
       2     1
       3     2
       3     4
       4     2
       4     1
```

I want the results when looking for 'cv' that related to `tech.id=1` and `tech.id=2`
to be like this

**results**

```
-----------------
Arthur
king
```

and not the results :

**results**

```
-----------------
Arthur
James
king
John
```

It's like saying :

```
- CV00 --> Java, PHP
- CV01 --> Java, C#
- CV02 --> PHP, Django
```

and I want the techs: Java and PHP that a CV haves, what I mean is CV00 not CV01 and CV02

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You have to provide some code we can see what's wrong with it and help you. BTW, in your `Bridge` table, you have `CV_id`s of **1, 2, 3, 4** for `tech_id` of **1** and **2**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join based on a subquery for the value IN the set you are looking for and that match for 2 value

```
    select name 
    from  cv_table c
    inner join (
        select distinct b.CV_id
        from bridge b 
        where b.tech_id in (1,2)
        group by CV_id 
        having count(distinct tech_id) = 2 
    ) t on t.CV_id = c.id
```